# Поставить пробел в .xml (php DOM)

Tags: php, dom

Подскажите как поставить пробел перед закрытием элемента xml.

Т.е. перед знаком "/>"
`<lcd Language="1" WebLanguage="1" />`
По умолчанию в этом месте не ставится пробел. Мне в рамках задачи нужно чтобы ставился этот пробел (особенность конфига).
Речь идёт о создании некоего конфига формата  xml  с помощью php DOM. Результатом будет создание простого xml файла, однако (к сожалению) **без** пробела после последнего аттрибута перед закрытием. Есть ли какое-то решение средствами php чтобы пробел ставился ?
Ведь между атрибутами пробел  стоит же.

```
$local_config = new DOMDocument('1.1', 'utf-8');
$local_config->formatOutput = true;
$all = $local_config->createElement('all');
$lcds = $local_config->createElement('lcds');
$lcd = $local_config->createElement('lcd');
$all->appendChild($lcds);
$lcds->appendChild($lcd);
$lcd->setAttribute('Language', 1);
$lcd->setAttribute('WebLanguage', 1);
$local_config->save($directory_for_config .'config' . '.xml');
```

Comment: единственное, что может побудить добавить пробел туда, где форматом он в целом не требуется, это какой-то очень люто костыльный метод дальнейшей работы с этим конфигом. Подумайте дважды, стоит ли писать костыль для костыля. Сегодня вам нужен пробел перед закрытием, завтра потребуете пробел в массиве JSON? Есть форматы, все штатные средства нормально с ними работают без всяких пробелов. Решение-костыль тут очевидное. сохранить не в файл, а в строку, потом заменить все `"/>` на `" />`, сохранить в файл.

Comment: спасибо, буду знать. Победили особенность конфига. Формат xml сохранён, всё работает без пробела. Спасибо  Вам за напутствие "не делать костыль".                                                              П.С. дело было в орфографической ошибке одного из агрументов.